# How do we control, Text rendering in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, text-rendering

In the following image we can observe that, the text displayed/rendered displayed differently.
       But the application is same and they were just run on 2 different windows 7 machines.
 [image]

Please help me understand the machine settings and the changes needed to correct, so that both display similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First version has ClearType turned off. It's controlled in windows in Display options.

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/ClearTypeInfo.mspx
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/306527/en